# how to retrieve NV21 data from DJI camera Phantom 3 Professional drone

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, yuv, wikitude, dji-sdk

As I described in a previous post, I'm working on an Android mobile app oriented to the real time augmented visualization of a drone's camera view (specifically I'm working on a DJI Phantom 3 Professional with relative SDK), using Wikitude framework for the AR part. Thanks to [Alex's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41873516/6950331), I implemented my own [Wikitude Input Plugin](http://www.wikitude.com/external/doc/documentation/latest/android/inputpluginsapi.html#input-plugins-api) in combination with [dji's Video Stream Decoding](https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/sample-code/index.html).

I have some issues now. First of all, "DJI's Video Stream Decoding" demo uses FFmpeg for video frame parsing and MediaCodec for hardware decoding. So, it helps to parse video frames and decode the raw video stream data from DJI Camera and output the YUV data. You adviced me to "get the raw video data from the dji sdk and pass it to the Wikitude SDK": since Wikitude Input Plugin needs YUV 420 format, arranged to be compliant to the NV21 standard in order to provide the custom camera, I should pass to it the YUV data output of the MediaCodec, right?

About this point, I tried to retrieve bytebuffers from the MediaCodec output (and this is possible by setting Surface parameter to null into configure() method, which have the effect to invoke a callback and pass it out to an external listener), but I'm having some issues about colours in visualization, because the encoded video colour is not right (blue and red seem to be reversed, and there is too much noise when camera moves).. (please note that, when I pass a Surface not null, after the instruction codec.releaseOutputBuffer(outIndex, true), MediaCodec renders frames on that and shows video stream properly, but I need to pass the video stream to Wikitude Plugin and so I must set surface to null).

I tried to set different MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT but none of them works properly. How can I solve this point?

Answer (score 0):

When decoding into bytebuffers with MediaCodec, you can't decide what color format the buffer uses; the decoder decides, and you have to deal with it. Each decoder can use a different format; some of them can be a standard format like `COLOR_FormatYUV420Planar` (corresponding to I420) or `COLOR_FormatYUV420SemiPlanar` (corresponding to NV12 - not NV21), while others can use completely proprietary formats.

See e.g. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/jb-mr2-release/tests/tests/media/src/android/media/cts/EncodeDecodeTest.java#401 for an example on what formats the decoder can return that are supported, and https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/jb-mr2-release/tests/tests/media/src/android/media/cts/EncodeDecodeTest.java#963 for a reference showing that it is ok for decoders to return private formats.

You can have a look at e.g. http://git.videolan.org/?p=vlc.git;a=blob;f=modules/codec/omxil/qcom.c;h=301e9150ae66075ca264e83566504802ed57578c;hb=bdc690e9c0e2516c00a6d3733a77a87a25d9b6e3 for an example on how to interpret one common proprietary color format.